# Timestamp proto and other proto files are not found eventhough they exist in /usr/local/bin/include/google/protobuf

Tags: ubuntu, protocol-buffers

I had this issue:

```
grpc_tools._protoc_compiler.ProtocErrors: google/protobuf/timestamp.proto:-1:0 error: File not found.
google/protobuf/any.proto:-1:0 error: File not found.
google/protobuf/field_mask.proto:-1:0 error: File not found.
google/protobuf/duration.proto:-1:0 error: File not found.
```

It is indeed here:

```
usr/local/bin/include/google/protobuf
```

[image: inside the protobuf folder]

I checked `sudo which protoc`, it gave me:

```
/usr/local/bin/protoc
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. Anyone has idea? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The directory should be:

`/usr/local/include`

**not**

`/usr/local/bin/include`

> **NOTE** because `protoc` has a pretty rapid release velocity, I've always tended to just download it to project directories and path it from there... e.g. `PATH=${PATH}:${PWD}/protoc-${VERS}-${ARCH}/bin`.